# Percent Log Used above threshold

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

**Alert: The SQL Server performance counter 'Percent Log Used' (instance 'dbname') of object 'SQLServer:Databases' is now above the threshold**

I tried the following:

---

1. backup log dbname with truncate_only

   BACKUP LOG dbname WITH TRUNCATE_ONLY
2. shrink the log file using dbcc shrinkfile

   ```
    DBCC SHRINKFILE(dbname_log, 1)
   ```

I am using **sipmle recovery model**, please suggest

Comment: What does "*still no luck*" mean?  Tell us exactly what actually happened and what you expected/hoped would happen.

Comment: What does the log_reuse_wait_desc column in sys.databases say for your database? That will tell you why your log is not being reused and is growing.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot take log backup when u are in SIMPLE Recover Mode. In Simple mode, this percent log growth issue will not arise altogether

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: Log files can get filled up for a database that is in SIMPLE recovery. For example, if someone tries to update a large amount of data in one statement or if someone holds an open transaction.

Comment: True....It can...but it will not remain so for long....by definition the tran log gets truncated at checkpoints